# Are dynamic arrays actually dynamic?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I'm reading about dynamic arrays (specifically at https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/dynamically-allocating-arrays/), and it seems to me that dynamic arrays are not actually dynamic, in that the size allocated for them cannot be changed.

If I am understanding correctly, the main use or point of dynamic arrays vs fixed arrays is that dynamic arrays will be allocated on the heap rather than the stack, and therefore can be larger. The terms "dynamic" and "fixed" give me the impression that one can be changed and the other cannot, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Is this correct, or am I misunderstanding something about dynamic vs fixed arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Dynamic" refers not to size, but to allocation method. In most C++ implementations there's several methods of storing data, but the two relevant here are local, as in on the stack, and dynamic, as in on the heap.

Dynamic tends to mean "allocated with `new`" or a similar mechanism, while stack allocations happen implicitly.

```cpp
X* x = new X[20]; // "Dynamic" array
X x[20]; // Local array
```

Neither of these can be easily resized.

A dynamic array can be *reallocated* and resized, while a stack one cannot, the size on the stack is fixed. This makes dynamic arrays more flexible in that regard, but it's not something that comes for free, you need to do a lot of work to implement that to ensure that your newly allocated object is consistent and that all pointers to it have been updated.

Additionally, the *lifetime* is different, as dynamically allocated structures have an indefinite lifetime, as the programmer you control that, while local variables have a scope-defined lifetime that is non-negotiable. When you exit the scope, they're gone.

Dynamic allocations come with considerable overhead on the part of the programmer, you're responsible for managing that lifecycle or delegating it to a wrapper that can do it for you, like a [smart pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers).

In modern C++ using actual low-level arrays is difficult and error-prone which is why `std::vector` is typically used instead. It provides way more guarantees and helps manage lifecycles for you if used effectively. The implementation of these manages resizing, and object deletion for you.

Answer (score 3):

Dynamic arrays are dynamic i.e. they have dynamic lifetime / dynamic storage (i.e. they are stored in free store aka "heap").

Dynamic arrays are also dynamic in the sense that unlike array variables, their size can be determined at runtime i.e. it doesn't need to be compile time constant. Example:

```
int size;
std::cin >> size;
auto ptr = std::make_unique<int[]>(size); // dynamic
int arr[size]; // ill-formed
```

You're correct in that the size of a (dynamic) array cannot change through its lifetime. Thus, a dynamic array in C++ isn't the abstract data structure by the same name, also known by names "growable array", "resizable array", "dynamic table", "mutable array", or "array list". The C++ standard library has implementation of that data structure by the name `std::vector`.